# What is the status on the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

How would we make the blog active if someone wanted to make blog posts (not naming Joannealaska...)

What types of topics are good or bad for the blog?

Comment: @joannealaska This one is for you.

Comment: I don't think anything's changed, we just haven't been posting to it. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/call-for-participation-cooking-blog?rq=1

Comment: Jolene! Not Joanne!

Comment: @Jolenealaska Sorry, I am bad with names... I got the Jo part right, at least.

Comment: I could totally see posting to the blog. I think I can get some IMDb Food and Drink people here too (although they'll be like I was at first, bristling at oh so seriousness of it all).

Comment: This site's strengths come from its focus, in my opinion.

Comment: @Jolenealaska There are other forums whose strengths lie in those areas.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I don't know, focus can also become tunnel vision. When we're dealing with a subject matter that is as much art as science, I think there is such a thing as being too rigid. I certainly don't think it is in our best interest to run off people who tend to approach making incredible food as an exercise in creativity.

Comment: It's still essentially invisible - until they make some design changes so that logged-in users see a link to it which isn't hidden in the footer, there's not much point having a blog.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I think that most of the topics we shun are equally irrelevant to people who consider cooking an art as they are to those who consider it a science. Health, because it's mostly junk science and even in the best case strays very far from the topic of making incredible food; and recipe requests, because anyone can Google those and the best answers quickly drown in an ocean of me-toos. We *want* the creative types as well as scientific, and a large part of what we do is try to filter out the noise and make interesting topics easy for them to find. We may not always succeed, but...

Comment: As far as seriousness where things like titles and tags are concerned, that has to stay. Once place where old-school forums really fall flat is in the area of *search*. Ever tried to find a thread more than 6 months old that wasn't stickied? Good luck. It may take some getting used to, but it's something that's important for everyone to understand. Possibly it may rub some people the wrong way, but it's never done with the *intention* of "running them off". Anyway, the blog and chat are the two places where there *aren't* really any rules, so people who find Q&A confining should be interested.

Comment: When it comes to tags and titles, I completely agree. Granted, it took me a while to get it, but at first I didn't realize what makes this site different from other places where I discuss cooking. Where I still have a bit of an issue is not allowing questions that are "primarily opinion based". For instance, I have ingredient X, what might make a good flavor counterpoint?

Comment: @Jolenealaska: [We *do* allow those](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1742/41), but the devil's in the details. The key word in that phrase is "primarily".

Comment: LOL...Funny you should have one with *just* the right wording! (and no, I hadn't seen it...reading now) [later]But...but...but...sometimes a great answer is neither *right* nor *wrong*

Comment: In other words, why is "polling" so awful? The information that migrates to the top is still valuable.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: It *might* be valuable, but most of the time it isn't. We know this from years of experience. People seem to shift into a different frame of mind when confronted with a poll; they vote based on random factors, like their preference for the thing described in the answer, or its entertainment value, or simply pile their votes onto everyone else's, but almost *never* vote based on the actual quality of the answer. It's clear that something's broken when you have answers with *thousands* of votes alongside equally-good answers that have almost 0 votes.

Comment: To be clear, if someone asked the question *"What's the best blender for X?"*, a truly *valuable* answer would be one that tests various different brands and models for task *X*, shares the results, gives a tentative ranking, and is continually updated as new blender models are produced. This almost *never* happens in practice; you just get an extremely-difficult-to-navigate list of everyone's favourites with no context whatsoever, and that is *not* valuable for a Q&A site because you could get the same (or likely better) results just by Googling for reviews.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, all of the blog admins (rumtscho, Jefromi, and myself) can still approve posts, accounts, etc... So the best bet would be for whoever wants to write something to bug one of us on chat.